# UISwitch in accessory view of a tableviewcell, passing a parameter with the selector to have selector function see the indexpath.row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiswitch

I have a `UISwitch` in a tableviewcontroller, and when the switch is toggled I want it to change the value of a boolean variable in an array I created inside the view controller, that the cell is related to. Kind of like the Stock Alarm App on IOS, where each cell has a `UISwitch`, and toggling the switch will turn off each individual alarm. So with the `UISwitch`, with its selector code, this is inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
//switch
    let lightSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero) as UISwitch
    lightSwitch.on = false
    lightSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchTriggered), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    //lightSwitch.addTarget(self, action: "switchTriggered", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged )

    cell.accessoryView = lightSwitch
```

I want it to do this

```
func switchTriggered(a: Int) {
    changeValueOfArray = array[indexPath.row]
}
```

I don't have the code written for that part yet, but my question is, How can i let the switchTriggered function see the `indexPath.row` value, without passing it as an argument to the function because I can't because its a selector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
let lightSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero) as UISwitch
    lightSwitch.on = false
    lightSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchTriggered), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    lightSwitch.tag = indexpath.row
    cell.accessoryView = lightSwitch
```

Let save your boolean value in  Array

```
    func switchTriggered(sender: UISwitch) {
      sender.on ? array[sender.tag]=1 : array[sender.tag]=0
     }
}
```

Comment: one question more how i know button is on or off?

Comment: Basically i want to change value on switch on/off so how i implement it using this way?

Comment: @ShahbazAkram by calling sender.isOn

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea is that you can capture the cell for which the switch was flipped and then use `tableView.indexPath(for:)` to translate that `UITableViewCell` reference into a `NSIndexPath`, and you can use its `row` to identify which row in your model structure needs to be updated.

The constituent elements of this consist of:

1. Create a model object that captures the information to be shown in the table view. For example, let's imagine that every cell contains a `name` of a `Room` and a boolean reflecting whether the light is on:

   ```
   struct Room {
       var name: String
       var lightsOn: Bool
   }
   ```
2. Then the table view controller would have an array of those:

   ```
   var rooms: [Room]!
   ```
3. I'd define a `UITableViewCell` subclass with outlets for the label and the switch. I'd also hook up the "value changed" for the light switch to a method in that cell. I'd also set up a protocol for the cell to inform its table view controller that the light switch was flipped:

   ```
   protocol RoomLightDelegate: class {
       func didFlipSwitch(for cell: UITableViewCell, value: Bool)
   }

   class RoomCell: UITableViewCell {

       weak var delegate: RoomLightDelegate?

       @IBOutlet weak var roomNameLabel: UILabel!
       @IBOutlet weak var lightSwitch: UISwitch!

       @IBAction func didChangeValue(_ sender: UISwitch) {
           delegate?.didFlipSwitch(for: self, value: sender.isOn)
       }

   }
   ```

   I'd obviously set the base class for the cell prototype to be this `UITableViewCell` subclass and hook up the `@IBOutlet` references as well as the `@IBAction` for the changing of the value for the switch.
4. I'd then have the `UITableViewDataSource` methods populate the cell on the basis of the `Room` properties:

   ```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return rooms.count
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SwitchCell", for: indexPath) as! RoomCell

       let room = rooms[indexPath.row]

       cell.roomNameLabel.text = room.name
       cell.lightSwitch.setOn(room.lightsOn, animated: false)
       cell.delegate = self

       return cell
   }
   ```
5. Note, the above `cellForRowAtIndexPath` also specifies itself as the `delegate` for the cell, so we'd want to implement the `RoomLightDelegate` protocol to update our model when the light switch is flipped:

   ```
   extension ViewController: RoomLightDelegate {

       func didFlipSwitch(for cell: UITableViewCell, value: Bool) {
           if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
               rooms[indexPath.row].lightsOn = value
           }
       }

   }
   ```

Now, I don't want you to worry about the details of the above. Instead, try to capture some of the basic ideas:

Bottom line, to your immediate question, once you know which cell was was updated, you can inquire with the `UITableView` to determine what `NSIndexPath` that `UITableViewCell` reference corresponds to, using `tableView.indexPath(for:)`.

Comment: From step 3 on, are those classes and protocols in the view controller?

Comment: Steps 4 and 5 are methods for the view controller, but step 3 is the separate class for the cell (plus the protocol to which the view controller conforms in step 5).

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 Update:

```
let lightSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRect.zero) as UISwitch
lightSwitch.isOn = false
lightSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchTriggered), for: .valueChanged)
lightSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
cell?.accessoryView = lightSwitch
```