# Is it language appropriate to layer a UIButton over a UILabel in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, uilabel

My question is this: Is this following approach to making a UILabel tap sensitive stylistically acceptable in the Swift 3 language?  I'm tempted to say "if it compiles it flies" but I don't want to get in the habit of using this "short cut" if it is going to bite me later on.  Further, if it is acceptable, are there some drawbacks to using this method that aren't obvious to a newcomer like me?

Please note that I am not looking for a way to implement code, I have one.  I am asking if the solution I have is acceptable from a language style perspective.

---

I've been trying to get a UILabel to accept a TapGesture when inside a table cell for 2 days now and whatever method I try, there is always some sort of error even if it will compile.  On a hunch, I went to my storyboard for the table view and added a button **on top** (not stacked, or aligned, or anything like that – actually occupying the same 2D space on the story board) within the prototype cell.  I deleted the button text, linked it to the table view cell code and implemented some basic functionality to change the text on the UILabel to red and back.  All of this functions exactly like I expected.  I click the button and the text changes from black to red, and back when clicked again.  The UILabel text is static in the table cell on a white background and my real function isn't going to change the text, it is going to alter another view through delegation from that view.

Why do it this way?  Even if I check the UILabel use interaction box and follow some of the other questions and answers here to make it tap-able, I cannot control+drag the UILabel to the table view cell and make an action, the option simply doesn't exist in the pull down menu.  It is available if I control+drag the UILabel to the table view controller.  This makes a kind of sense to me because it is the table view controller that senses touch (right?).  But, on the other hand, I have a switch in the table view cell that works just fine when I follow the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566065/uiswitch-in-accessory-view-of-a-tableviewcell-passing-a-parameter-with-the-sele).  Simple functionality of the storyboard-code interation (control+drag) is preventing me from getting what I want.  Maybe control+drag should be allowing me to make an action and doesn't?  I don't know.  I don't want to use a UIButton alone because the text scaling feature of UILabel is really handy.

Comment: Look into open-source subclasses of UILabel that support link detection and user interaction, such as [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel), [ZSWTappableLabel](https://github.com/zacwest/ZSWTappableLabel), etc

Comment: What does your question have to do with Swift 3? It's the same whether you use Swift 2, Swift 3, Objective-C, or some other language.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm trying to be specific to what I am doing.  Your assertion that language style is the same across all languages is not true at all.   Otherwise I could use python list comprehension in Swift.  Your question does beg the answer that as long as it compiles, it is ok.

Comment: You missed my point. Your question has nothing to do with the language you are using. You are asking about general approaches with an API that happens to support multiple languages. There is absolutely nothing in your question that is specific to Swift. Adding labels and buttons and using table views is all the same regardless of the language. Once you choose the best approach, of course the exact details of how that approach is coded varies slightly between Swift and Objective-C but you are not asking anything at that low level.

Comment: Your response is fine as far as it goes, but that isn't very far.  If I scrubbed the question of all references to Swift, would that improve it in your eyes?  Please note that there are follow up questions to the main one that are most definitely language specific, maybe UIButtons will "walk around" the screen when compared to the UILabel when using Xcode/Swift but not in some other language.

Comment: I find it hard to read through long paragraphs with no code. :-) But if I read this correctly, you (1) cannot add a tap gesture to a UILabel that is (2) in a UITableView or UITableViewCell, even though (3) you can get a UISwitch to work. The next step - one I didn't catch in your question - would be: Can you get a add a tap gesture successfully to a "plain" UILabel?

Comment: @dfd I can't get the tap gesture to work on the UILabel, no.  But I can plaster a UIButton over the UILabel that will do everything I want (so far).  Getting the tap gesture to work isn't my question though.  

There is nothing superficially wrong with this method, it works, but I don't know iOS programming enough to know if it is acceptable to other programmers or if it will do weird things when the table moves, or whatever, I don't know that is why I am asking.  I'm trying to learn to be a good Swift/iOS programmer, not just some person that rigs code lines like I'm casting spells.

Comment: Well, using code, I *can* get a UITapGestureRecognizer to work with a UILabel. Without pasting a UIButton over it. IMHO that's the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to recognize taps on the table cell, make the class the delegate of the table view

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

and implement

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //your code here
    }
```

I'd also appreciate you taking the time to read a bit more about UITableViews. Every UITableViewCell has a label by itself. Consider the following code:

```
tableView.dataSource = self // this code will ideally be in init

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "lovCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = dummyData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```