# swift: TableView.insertRows give wrong indexPath

Tags: swift

I'm doing a `tableView.insertRows(at:[IndexPath(row: 0, section: indexPath.section)] , with: .fade)` when a cell get edited  with this the help of this function `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?`
(I of course insert a new record in my data array to be shown)

The problem is when a cell get inserted on top of the table the cell that was on top must get `indexPath.row = 1`, but no when I inspect it I see that both the cell inserted and the cell that was on top got the `indexPath.row = 0`

so when I select the new added cell I get `indexPath.row = 0`
as well as when I select the second cell that was on the top

**I have a multicolumn Table using collectionViews inside tableViewCells**

[image]

Comment: You're not saving the `IndexPath` as a property of the cell are you? The fact that they can change as rows are inserted or deleted is precisely why we don't do that.

Comment: Actually I am, but because i need to know the indexPath of the cell so I can know witch one was selected, - I am using  a custom cell witch have some views on it - , the `didSelectRowAt`dose not fire, I had to handle it myself, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You really don't want to be in the business of storing an index path in the cell. Cells can theoretically be inserted/deleted/moved, so the index path is not a property of the cell, but rather something managed by the table view  If you find your cell wanting an index path, it is generally an indication of some design flaw (e.g. that the cell is trying to do something that the table view's controller really should be doing). We'd need more context of the broader design to advise how to solve this.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39566554/1271826 for an example where the cell had a switch which it wanted to update the model. So I set up a protocol to have cell inform its delegate that the switch was flipped, and then the view controller takes care of updating the model. I don't know if this is close enough to your situation to be helpful, but hopefully it illustrates the idea of delegating the index path related stuff back to the table view controller.

Comment: So instead of saving indexPath inside a cell, I must return the cell itself to the tableView who will know what this cell's indexPath should be?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. Effectively the cell tells the table view controller "hey, this event happened in this cell", and the table view controller can do the necessary model update (or what have you).

Comment: Is this following the `Delegation pattern` thing that i read about in the docs?
and what I was doing was just a work around it

Comment: Yep. And generally, to keep our classes loosely coupled, we formalize the interface employed by the delegation pattern with a protocol. (I fact, we do this so much, you'll sometimes see it referred to collectively as the delegate-protocol pattern.)